# Uniform convergence in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f_n(x)=x+ \dfrac{1}{n}$ where $x \in (0,1)$ and the metric

$$d(x,y)=\vert \dfrac{1}{x}- \frac{1}{y} \vert $$

How can I prove that $f_n$ don't converges uniformly to $f : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=x$.

My attempt was:

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $sup_{x\in (0,1)} \{ d(f_n(x),f(x)) \} = sup_{x\in (0,1)} \lbrace \dfrac{1}{(nx+1)x} \rbrace = \infty $. But I can´t prove that.

Answer (score 1):

The sup of a set is at least as big as any member of the set. So
$$
\sup_{x\in(0,1)} \left| \frac1{(nx+1)x}\right|\ge \left|\frac1{(n\frac1n+1)\frac1n}\right|=\frac n{2}
$$
(We are comparing the sup over $x \in(0,1)$ with the member where $x=\frac1n$.)
Since this is true for every $n$, conclude the sup is $\infty$.

Comment: So the sup is taken over $n$ too.

Comment: @Orested Yes, you could write $\sup_{x\in(0,1)}|g(x)|\ge\sup_n |g(\frac1n)|=\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

Note that since $\frac{1}{n} \in (0,1),$

$$\sup_{x\in (0,1)} \left\{ \dfrac{1}{(nx+1)x} \right\} \geqslant \dfrac{1}{(n\cdot \frac{1}{n}+1)\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{n}{2} ,$$

and the RHS diverges as $n \to \infty$.